# Typescript fails to infer props when destructuring props with rest syntax

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a custom generic type that uses React's `ComponentProps` internally.
When I create the type of a component's props using this custom type, TS behaves strangely.
Here is a simple example:
[Codesandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/clever-waterfall-kkqhp?file=/src/Foo.tsx)

You can see in the link above that when I use `PropsWithAs` generic type, TS only understands that `fallbackText` is in the props if I access it directly. But it fails to get the fact that `fallbackText` is in in the `rest` variable when I use rest syntax.

```
type Props<T extends ElementType = "div"> = PropsWithAs<
  T,
  {
    fallbackText: string;
    counter: number;
  }
>;

const Foo = <T extends ElementType>(props: Props<T>): JSX.Element => {
  // fallbackText is present and identified by TS here without any issue:
  const { fallbackText } = props;
  
  const { counter, ...rest } = props;

  // But TS doesn't see that `rest` also includes fallbackText here:
  return <Bar {...rest} />;
};
```

Comment: Please include code as text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the definition of PropsWithAs. I don't really understand why you are using `& Omit<ComponentProps<T>, keyof U>`, it seems to be the contrary of what you want.

Anyways, if you remove that piece of code everything should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks, so why are they available in the first example? How am I able to access them if they are omitted?

Comment: From what I can see, the problem arises when nesting multiple Omits. Before deconstructing you only have 1 Omit and it works fine. After the deconstruction it looks as if typescript is messing something up.

Comment: Testing this hypothesis, if you change the definition with 
const Foo = <T extends ElementType = "div">(
  props: Omit<Props<T>, "whatever">
)
You will see that typescript can no longer infer the type of counter as a number but as Props<T>[string].

So I really think something is wrong nesting Omit. My suggestion would be to use Exclude

Comment: Thank you, yeah it makes sense. The thing is using Exclude just works in your example, but it doesn't work if I use it in `PropsWithAs`. Also, I think it only works for union types if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I found the problem

```
Omit<ComponentProps<T>, keyof U>
```

this is because omit remove from the type the keys you want
[ts document  about omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys)
It means that you remove from the T the U keys it doesn't mean you gonna have  those keys in the rest if they do not exist in the T

Comment: Thank you! I wanted to not have a conflict between props. For example, if T is ="img" and my component has an "src" prop itself, I wanted to have component's "src" in the end.

Comment: well for image you can extend this HTMLImageElement to the props
and then put in the Curly braces the rest of the props you wanted

Comment: The thing is the `as` prop would be used in a dynamic way. It couldn't and wouldn't be something hard-coded. So, I want to make sure that there is no conflict when a developer wants to use this type as a helper. Anyways, I guess we are thinking in two different directions. My first question is: If TS is omitting "fallbackText" (that I don't think so), why it's still available if I access it directly (without rest syntax)?